# Changing from 32 bit to 64 bit

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

My solution in Visual Studio 2012 has three projects. A WinForms project and two VC++ projects (Libraries). Initially all the development was done on a Windows 7 Professional 32 Bit. But recently, my system was updated to Windows 7 Professional 64 Bit.

My application builds and runs successfully with Active Solution Platform set to AnyCPU. But when the application launches and I perform some action which makes a call to the underlying VC++ Library, the application crashes with a `FileNotFoundException` for the dll.

So should I change the Active Solution Platform to x64? Or is it fine to leave it as it is.

I have tried to change the Active Solution Platform to x64. But the dll doesnot build. I get a `error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol`

I have never used a 64-bit before. What should I do to make my application build?

The symbols that are not being found are present in the third VC++ project which is a static library.

The WinForms depends on the dll and the dll depends on the static lib.

Update:

When the Build Configuration is set to AnyCPU, I get a `System.BadImageFormatException`. Under additional information, it says could not load file or assembly `dll_name,....`. Attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: Why don't you tell us more about the error you're getting. What symbol is unresolved?

Comment: Unless there's a compelling reason for the application to run in 64-bit mode, it is likely to be simpler to leave it as 32-bit.  That means setting the Active Solution Platform to x86.

Comment: 64-bit processes can't call 32-bit dlls and vice versa. You must make sure that all the calling functions in your program are 64-bit version

Comment: compile your application with 64 bit is the only way (As your using windows)

Comment: @DigviJayPatil: why not 32 bits?

Comment: 32 or 64 bit doesn't matter, as long as **everything** matches.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I have not made any changes to the configuration or solution. I am running the same solution which I used in 32 bit. But when the application reaches the code where the dll is used, it crashes.

Comment: *Everything matches* includes all the DLLs you are using.  If any of them is 32-bit only, your code must also be 32-bit.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Like I mentioned, all the code was for 32 bit. Not after changing the operating system, I get these linker errors

Comment: It doesn't sound like you have ever built the main application for x86.  If you have 32 bit library dependencies, then building for x64 will always fail, and AnyCPU will fail on 64 bit OS.  Unless you have 64bit versions of all the third party libraries, you will need to use 32 bits everywhere explicitly.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Can you post your comment as an answer? I changed the Active Solution Platform from AnyCPU to x86 and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AnyCPU platform choice builds CPU-independent .NET code.  This means it will run as x86 code on 32-bit Windows but as x64 code on 64-bit Windows.

Visual C++ doesn't have any equivalent to AnyCPU.  Those projects must either be 32-bit or 64-bit.  Presumably, your solution is configured to build them as 32-bit DLLs when AnyCPU is selected.  This means that on a 64-bit machine, the .NET code will be running as 64-bit but the DLLs will still be 32-bit, and since a 64-bit process can't load a 32-bit DLL, it won't work.

You can fix this *either* by setting the Active Solution Platform to x64 or by setting it to x86.  Unless you have a specific reason why you want the code to run as x64 (e.g., it requires the larger address space, or it does not perform well on a 32-bit platform) it is usually simpler to choose x86, because that will work on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, and does not require any modification to existing code originally developed for 32-bit Windows.

It is also possible to build both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs within a single solution, and have the .NET code load whichever is appropriate at runtime.  However, this is more complicated.